# Does api.query.session.validators return a Collators list on Astar Network?

Tags: astar

As a title, I'd like to confirm that api.query.session.validators interface return a Collators list on Astar Network to check if our collator works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It returns a list of current validators.

Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e5d5d88d0d0e79042393c8bc85e5e9ebe6a24000/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L502-L505.

But it doesn't mean your collator works well. Suppose your collator stops producing/collecting blocks. It might still be on the list for a while.